# Move uploaded file into Application/views/myfolder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just having troubles with the moving files script. the script is outside CI in the root folder in a folder called "application-native" but needs to move the uploaded files into the `application/views/business/media/external-videos/`.

I already tried `../application/views/business/media/external-videos/`, `../".APPPATH.'/views/business/media/external-videos/`.

I'm getting the warning `404 page not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently i didn't update the path on my form action! lol